# Can the STL map comparator somehow get the pointer to the map itself?

Tags: c++, stl

can the STL map comparator somehow obtain the pointer to the map itself (or any other external parameter), in addition to pointers to the values being compared?

I want to use an STL map as an index into some binary data consisting of variable-length records, and I would prefer to just store offsets in the map, with the comparator looking up actual values using these offsets.

But for this to work, the comparator needs to know the base address of the data block (to add the offsets to). Using pointers instead of offsets is not an option, because the data block can be moved in memory. So I would prefer to store this base pointer in a subclass of std::map and retrieve it in the comparator. And for that, the comparator must somehow know the address of the map object. Is this possible?

I understand I can include a pointer to the map object into every map key, but it would waste memory. Is there a more straightforward method of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: i dont really understand what you want to achieve, though I understand even less how a pointer to the map would help. If you know how to do it by including a pointer to the map in every key then maybe write that as example, currently the question is rather unclear

Comment: I want to store offsets in the map rather than pointers. So the comparator needs an additional parameter (base address) to compare values at the specified offsets. How can I get that extra parameter into the comparator?

Comment: Yes, this is easily possible. Use a lambda (or just a class with `operator()` overloaded) that stores the base address that you need. A free function cannot do this (well, not in a thread-safe/reentrant way).

Comment: Also, please don't subclass `std::map`.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724547/c-lambda-expressions-capture-clause-vs-argument-list-what-is-the-crucial-dif/57726373#57726373)

Comment: Sounds like you may just want to write your own container interface owning a `std::map`. Even if you manage to come up with a clever trick to avoid this, think of the next person who will need to try to understand what you did or why you did it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can do this with a capturing lambda, e.g.:

```
#include <map>

struct map_data {};

int main ()
{
    map_data md;
    auto comparator = [&md] (int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs < rhs; };
    std::map <int, int, decltype (comparator)> my_map (comparator);
    my_map.find (5);
}
```

The base address of your binary data is then available within the lambda via `&md`.